# How to remove sublists whose last digit is odd?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to remove any sub-lists whose last digit is odd. My attempt below does not look elegant because I convert each sub-list of digits to a number first and then remove the odd numbers.

## Question

How can I filter the `input` by checking the last digit in each sub-list? Using a single `DeleteCases` if preferred.

## Attempt

```
ClearAll[input, output, final]
input = Permutations@IntegerDigits@444123;
output = FromDigits /@ DeleteCases[input, {___, 4, 4 .., ___}];
final = DeleteCases[output, x_?OddQ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input={{4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}};
DeleteCases[input, _List?(OddQ[#[[-1]]] &)]

(*{{4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}}*)
```

or

```
DeleteCases[input, {___, a_} /; OddQ[a]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Pick[input, BitAnd[1, input[[All, -1]]], 0]
```

Should be quite snappy on large lists.

Answer (score 4):

```
Pick[input, Mod[Last /@ input, 2], 0]
Pick[input, EvenQ[Last /@ input]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input//Pick[#,OddQ@#[[All,-1]],False]&
```

or

```
input//Pick[#,Divisible[#[[All,-1]],2]]&
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3}, 
  {4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{__, _?OddQ}}]
```

{{4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

Some point-free variants:

```
input = {{4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 
    3}, {4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}};

f = OddQ@*Last;

DeleteCases[_?f][input]
Cases[_?(Not@*f)][input]
Select[Not@*f][input]
Pick[input, Not@*f /@ input]
Extract[input, Position[input[[All, -1]], _?EvenQ]]
```

and why did this one not occur to me before?

```
Select[EvenQ@*FromDigits][input]
```

---

> {{4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, 
        {4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1},
        {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}};
```

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {___, a_ /; ! OddQ[a]}, ___} :> s] (*Or EvenQ*)

(*{{4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {s : {___, a_ /; ! OddQ[a]}} :> s] (*Or EvenQ*)

(*{{4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}}*)
```

Or using `Replace`:

```
Replace[list, {___, a_ /; OddQ[a]} :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2}}*)
```

Comment: I am guilty of the same thing, and sometimes it is more natural to do so as you verbalize in your own (tech) language but `!OddQ` is `EvenQ`.

Comment: It's true @Syed, I also feel guilty about the same. :-)